# Grab variable data from .js an post to a php

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have an js file file.js that contains this

```
$(window).load(function(){
$.getJSON("json.json", 
function(person){
var client = person['name1'];
});
});
```

ant i use this to add client to my page , but now i want to post var client to a file.php page with post data like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/file.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
$.ajax({
type: 'post',
url: 'file.php',
data: {
ClientName: ""+client+"",
},
success: function( data ) {
console.log( data );
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

the var client is in file.js how to grab it from .js and use it in the other JavaScript from the posting page

the page works fine if i change  `"+client+"` with any world is posted to file.php.

but how to post the data from var client . ??

Comment: just use ClientName: client

Comment: No result i've tried,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scope of client variable is limited to your success block. declare client variable outside. like below:

```
var client = 0;
$(window).load(function(){
$.getJSON("json.json", 
function(person){
client = person['name1'];


       $.ajax({
       type: 'post',
       url: 'file.php',
      data: {
      ClientName: ""+client+"",
     },
    success: function( data ) {
    console.log( data );
    }
});
});
```

Comment: this is posting only "0"

Comment: actually call latter function from success block of previous function edited code to do that

Comment: the edited post work but i dont want the .js code to be in the same java code. i needdet to be in the js file!